# Corda ledger- partially hiding ledger data to other party

Tags: corda

Reference : [Corda: Gathering inputs from other parties in the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808685/corda-gathering-inputs-from-other-parties-in-the-network)

My requirement is there are 2 cordapps and cordapp 2 can query cordapp 1 and cordapp 1 should be able to share partial ledger data to cordapp2. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this as far as I know.
My understanding here is that when you share a state with a node, that node will get the entire state.

What might be possible is if you were to build a custom flow to get specific information but even then I don't think this is an ideal situation I'd be curious what the use case is where you'd want to do this (there's also anonymous and confidential parties if identity is what you're trying to not share.)

More info on that here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.6/cordapps/api-confidential-identity.html

Good luck!